# How to add a section header in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can I add a section header in UITableView?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

if you just want section header title, you can use UITableViewDataSource method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Or you can set you custom view as header using UITableViewDelegate method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

The controller implementing these, needs to be the delegate/datasource of your table view.

Answer (score 1):

After using UITableViewDelegate method:

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

you must also using UITableViewDelegate method:

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;`

to display the header.